# Generate a neshan map link with directions using latitude and longitude

Tags: dictionary, progressive-web-apps, navigator, neshan

I want to create a link using latitude and longitude for neshan app to use on the web.

the `redirectLink` variable is not work in `neshan.org`

```
   const redirectLink = `https://neshan.org/maps/@35.699658,51.390640,15.3z,0.0p/routing/destination/${lat},${lng}`;
    const shareData = {title: name, text: address, url: redirectLink}
    
    try {
        await navigator.share(shareData)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Share is Failed", err);
    }
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what is not working. Quote any error messages, or explain what is going wrong in more detail.

Comment: For example for generate [waze deep link](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks) link it's work: `https://waze.com/ul?ll=${lat},${lng}&z=10`.
but I don't know how I can generate link for [Neshan](https://platform.neshan.org/) because every model I make it does not work in App Neshan